# expectLater hangs when it runs the second test

Tags: flutter

I have a widget like so:

```dart
class StreamingSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  const StreamingSwitch({
    required this.controller,
    this.initialValue = false,
    // ... other params ...
    super.key,
  });

  final StreamController<bool> controller;
  final bool initialValue;
  // ... other fields ...

  @override
  State<StreamingSwitch> createState() => _StreamingSwitchState();
}

class _StreamingSwitchState extends State<StreamingSwitch> {
  late bool value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    value = widget.initialValue;
    widget.controller.add(value);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
      // ... other params ...
      value: value,
      onChanged: (val) {
        widget.controller.add(val);
        setState(() {
          value = val;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I wrap my test widgets on `MaterialApp` using this function:

```dart
Widget initMaterial(Widget widget) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(body: widget),
  );
}
```

And this is how I test my widget:

```dart
void main() {
  testWidgets('default', (tester) async {
    final controller = StreamController<bool>();
    final stream = controller.stream;
    final widget = StreamingSwitch(controller: controller);

    await tester.pumpWidget(initMaterial(widget));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    // await controller.close();
    await expectLater(stream, emitsInOrder([false]));
  });

  testWidgets('initial value', (tester) async {
    final controller = StreamController<bool>();
    final stream = controller.stream;
    final widget = StreamingSwitch(controller: controller, initialValue: true);

    await tester.pumpWidget(initMaterial(widget));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    // await controller.close();
    await expectLater(stream, emitsInOrder([false, true]));
  });
}
```

To explain, this widget is a switch that is supposed to stream its current value: `true` or `false`.

The problem is, `default` test runs just fine, but `initial value` test hangs. I have troubleshooted it with many ways but `initial value` test hangs on `expectLater` in `initial value` test.

Why does it hang there while it doesn't in `default` test?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- Flutter 3.10.3